# Quadratic Bezier Interpolation

Tags: animation, actionscript-2, bezier

I would like to get some code in AS2 to interpolate a quadratic bezier curve. the nodes are meant to be at constant distance away from each other. Basically it is to animate a ball at constant speed along a non-hyperbolic quadratic bezier curve defined by 3 pts.
Thanks!

Comment: I have already seen some complex mathematical stuff but it involves integrals which i do not know how to do in as2

Answer (score 6):

The Bezier curve math is really quite simple, so I'll help you out with that and you can translate it into ActionScript.

A 2D quadratic Bezier curve is defined by three `(x,y)` coordinates. I will refer to these as `P0 = (x0,y0)`, `P1 = (x1,y1)` and `P2 = (x2,y2)`. Additionally a parameter value `t`, which ranges from `0` to `1`, is used to indicate any position along the curve. All `x`, `y` and `t` variables are real-valued (floating point).

The equation for a quadratic Bezier curve is:

```
P(t) = P0*(1-t)^2 + P1*2*(1-t)*t + P2*t^2
```

So, using pseudocode, we can smoothly trace out the Bezier curve like so:

```
for i = 0 to step_count
    t = i / step_count
    u = 1 - t
    P = P0*u*u + P1*2*u*t + P2*t*t
    draw_ball_at_position( P )
```

This assumes that you have already defined the points `P0`, `P1` and `P2` as above. If you space the control points evenly then you should get nice even steps along the curve. Just define step_count to be the number of steps along the curve that you would like to see.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the expression can be done much more efficient mathematically.

```
P(t) = P0*(1-t)^2 + P1*2*(1-t)*t + P2*t^2
```

and

```
P = P0*u*u + P1*2*u*t + P2*t*t
```

both hold t multiplications which can be simplified.

For example:

`C = A*t + B(1-t) = A*t + B - B*t = t*(A-B) + B` = You saved one multiplication = Double performance.

Comment: While it might be true that you can save a few multiplies, the Bernstein basis is inherently more numerically stable. So if precision is a concern, the polynomial should *not* be reorganized. Admittedly, this won't matter much for animating a ball, but this is a huge deal in CAD packages.

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by Naaff, that is `P(t) = P0*(1-t)^2 + P1*2*(1-t)*t + P2*t^2`, will get you the correct "shape", but selecting evenly-spaced `t` in the `[0:1]` interval will not produce evenly-spaced `P(t)`. In other words, the speed is not constant (you can differentiate the previous equation with respect to `t` to see see it).

Usually, a common method to traverse a parametric curve at constant-speed is to reparametrize by arc-length. This means expressing `P` as `P(s)` where `s` is the length traversed along the curve. Obviously, `s` varies from zero to the total length of the curve. In the case of a quadratic bezier curve, there's a closed-form solution for the arc-length as a function of `t`, but it's a bit complicated. Computationally, it's often faster to just integrate numerically using your favorite method. Notice however that the idea is to compute the inverse relation, that is, `t(s)`, so as to express `P` as `P(t(s))`. Then, choosing evenly-spaced `s` will produce evenly-space `P`.